# SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services to export CSV

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs

I have an SQL Server 2012 Reporting Services instance, and by default, it can only export to PDF, Excel and Word. Users require CSV export as well.
All I found is that there are different extensions, but not clear how to add or install them.

This is what we have now:

[image]

Desirable (CSV is a must have, others would be good):

[image]

Update:

Using 64 bit version.

`<Render>` section of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config`:

```
    <Render>
        <Extension Name="XML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.XmlDataReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering"/>
        <Extension Name="NULL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.NullRenderer.NullReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.NullRendering" Visible="false"/>
        <Extension Name="CSV" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering"/>
        <Extension Name="ATOM" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.AtomDataReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering" Visible="false"/>
        <Extension Name="PDF" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.PDFRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ImageRendering"/>
        <Extension Name="RGDI" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.RGDIRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ImageRendering" Visible="false"/>
        <Extension Name="HTML4.0" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.Html40RenderingExtension,Microsoft.ReportingServices.HtmlRendering" Visible="false">
            <Configuration>
                <DeviceInfo>
                    <DataVisualizationFitSizing>Approximate</DataVisualizationFitSizing>
                </DeviceInfo>
            </Configuration>
        </Extension>
        <Extension Name="MHTML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.MHtmlRenderingExtension,Microsoft.ReportingServices.HtmlRendering">
            <Configuration>
                <DeviceInfo>
                    <DataVisualizationFitSizing>Approximate</DataVisualizationFitSizing>
                </DeviceInfo>
            </Configuration>
        </Extension>
        <Extension Name="EXCEL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering" Visible="false"/>
        <Extension Name="EXCELOPENXML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering"/>
        <Extension Name="RPL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RPLRendering.RPLRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.RPLRendering" Visible="false" LogAllExecutionRequests="false"/>
        <Extension Name="IMAGE" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ImageRenderer.ImageRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ImageRendering"/>
        <Extension Name="WORD" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering" Visible="false"/>
        <Extension Name="WORDOPENXML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.WordRenderer.WordOpenXmlRenderer.WordOpenXmlDocumentRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WordRendering"/>
    </Render>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a problem with your SQL Server edition.

I had the same issue on SQL 2012 express. As it was enabled in the config but not visible in the export list, I tried exporting via URL directly and got an error `rsRenderingExtensionNotFound`.

Checking in the logs of SSRS I found a line indicating that the XML extension was *removed* at startup because it was not supported by this edition.

A quick test on an SQL 2008 R2 Standard edition (I did not have and SQL 2012 Std at hand unfortunately) did show the CSV, XML (the one I was after) and other exports not listed on SQL Express.

I would therefore suggest upgrading your edition to standard to try to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but the instance I had the problem with was Standard Edition.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the extensions by editing the SSRS instance's rsreportserver.config file.  This file resides in your SSRS instance folder (`\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer` is the default).

Check to see if you have this line in your instance's config file (within the `<Render>` node:

```
  <Extension Name="CSV" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering" />
```

If so, check to see if it has the `Visible` attribute set to `false`.  If so, remove the `Visible` attribute and restart your SSRS instance.

Here are some relative links:

- [Customize Rendering Extension Parameters in RSReportServer.Config](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281.aspx)
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155365.aspx

Comment: Visible tag was not present. Restarted it, it's still not showing. Any other idea why it's not showing?

Comment: It's possible to disable them programatically.  Is this problem true for a brand new generic report as well?

Comment: I don't know. I just enabled SSRS on a fresh server and uploaded the reports, and this happens. Do you have any clue where/what could I check?

Comment: Can you post the content of the `<Render>` node from your rsreportserver.config file?

Comment: Yes, updated my question. Also indicated that using 64 bit version, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hmm, that certainly looks ok and is basically what my new clean instance looks like, but I get all of the extensions in the drop-down.  I wonder if specifically setting it to `Visible="true"` would do anything.  And I was wrong, you don't have to bounce the instance for this change; it's dynamic.